# Sorting of Month in Cross Table

Tags: business-intelligence, business-objects

Can anyone help me to sort Month in the Horizontal Tab of Cross Table in BO report? I am getting month in the below order:

Jan Feb March Apr May June July ... Dec

I want the month to be sorted like:

Apr May June July ... Dec Jan Feb March

In other places I need it only in Jan, Feb order. So I can't change it at universe level. Please suggest me some solution.

Thanks in Advance,

Riya

Comment: Are you actually sorting strings here, or are these dates which you are formatting to only show the month?

Answer (score 1):

What you're looking for is *custom sort*. This allows you to define a different sort order that the default ascending or descending order.

Have a look at the tutorial here: [Web Intelligence 4.0: Sort the data in a document](http://scn.sap.com/docs/DOC-21143). Custom sort is described at the end of the tutorial.

This is assuming that you're using BI4, however the same feature exists in XI3.

Comment: Hi Kristof ,Thanks for ur reply ..  I have seen the link shared by you . But That is not the answer I expected . The Months are the Column headers . I want to sort the Column headers . But those column headers are Coming directly from the database . I don't want to Change that in the database level . Do you have any solution to Change at the report level. Please guide me .

Answer (score 0):

This Sorting issue has been resolved by making each month as an individual Column by creating the necessary report variables.